# Using plugins with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, ractivejs

I'm using [ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org), an events plugin for it, [ractive-events-keys](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-events-keys), and browserify.

According to the usage for ractive-events-keys, I just need to `require()` it, and it'll install itself.  That isn't working however.  Upon closer inspection I realised I was getting two versions of ractive in my bundle (presumably because the plugin required it's own version), so I added a `browser.ractive` key to my package.json (kind of on a whim, but it seemed to work).  I now only have one Ractive bundled, but the key event plugin still doesn't work (i.e., I still get the warning telling me to install the plugin).

As far as I know, I don't need browserify-shim, because the modules were designed to work with CommonJS.

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Could you post your `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I have an `index.js` (browserify entry point) and load plugins like:

```
var Ractive = require('ractive');

// file reference:
/*var keys = */  require('./js/ractive-transitions-fade');

// npm reference:
/*var touch = */  require('ractive-touch');

var ractive = new Ractive({...})
```

The plugin "registers" itself, but you still have to "install" either as a file in your assets or via npm

Comment: yep, got that much, which is all I thought I would need.  unfortunately, it's not registering for some reason

Comment: Is it not in the bundle.js? Or is not "working" in the UI? Or?

Comment: it's in the bundle.js, but I still see the warning about the missing event in the console

Comment: Try `Ractive.events.escape` in the console and see if it exists or is `undefined`. If it exists it's an order of operations issue. If it doesn't exist, try putting a breakpoint in the function in the bundle and see if the module function is being called.